# How to interpret MANOVA results after adding gender, splitting the file?

Tags: variance, multivariate-analysis, spss, interpretation, manova

I am analyzing my 2x3 between subject design with MANOVA in SPSS at the moment.  In the main model, there is 2 IV's and 2 DV's.  Result of the test is 1 main effect and no interaction effect. In an extended model, I am adding gender as a IV. Results now show interaction effect of gender with both IV's.  Hence, I am interpreting those results (the effect of the IV's depends on gender).

Now, I was splitting the file by gender to get a deeper understanding and the results are completely different. Does it make sense to split the file by gender and run manovas again? I am a little puzzled now which results to interpret? Should I split the file or can you recommend any other follow-up tests?

Comment: By splitting the file you cannot analyze interactions. In what sense could that possibly provide a "deeper understanding"?  What are you hoping to accomplish, specifically?

Comment: Yes, true.. I saw other analysis that considered gender splitting the file. Just wanted to make sure that its the right procedure.

On another note: If the interaction is only significant on 1 DV, do I then interpret the main effect on the second DV?

Answer (score 2):

Splitting the dataset on gender is not a good idea. You lose the possibility to model and interpret the interactions (and you lose statistical power.) More concretely, splitting the file on gender is the same as **including all interactions with gender in the model** (well, in addition it gets more variance estimates.)  The full details can be found in my answer here:  [Separate Models vs Flags in the same model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/373890/separate-models-vs-flags-in-the-same-model/373909#373909)

Answer (score 1):

No, splitting the dataset into two does not gain you anything over simply using the full dataset and modelling the interaction.