# Power analysis for cox-ph model for 8 (correlated) groups?

Tags: correlation, survival, cox-model, statistical-power, biostatistics

I am investigating covariate X for 8 cancer types which all have different survival rates and will possibly show different impacts of other covariates like age, sex etc. Therefore I will run 8 separate cox-ph regressions.

However, I doubt X will behave completely differently for each cancer type. If it has no significant effect for 6 types, that probably informs us it won't for the remaining two types and vice versa for a significant effect. So there should be a lower sample size than a regular power analysis * 8. But how can I incorporate this correlation to reduce the sample size?

Comment: Many relevant Qs here:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/373890/separate-models-vs-flags-in-the-same-model, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/386877/how-to-interpret-manova-results-after-adding-gender-splitting-the-file/413140#413140, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/486373/is-there-a-benefit-to-splitting-the-data-by-gender-or-age-range-when-building-pr/486461#486461  and search this site!

Comment: This is not a power problem.  It is an estimation/precision problem.  See https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/sim.7992