# Difference between stratification and subset

Tags: stratification, subset

This may be a duplicate question asked differently, I am curious to know the difference between performing an analysis by stratification on a variable and by subsetting the dataset based on that variable.

Any suggestions or input is appreciated thanks.

Comment: Could you please give an example of each so we know what you mean?

Comment: I think that's the question.  If so, some context would be useful as 'stratified analysis' is used to mean quite different things in different contexts.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/373890/separate-models-vs-flags-in-the-same-model/373909#373909   is similar, but maybe your thinking of something else?