# Ordinal Regression with Categorical Predictors in R (Proportional Odds Logistic Regression)

Tags: r, regression, categorical-data, ordinal-data, ordered-logit

My independent variable is Party Identification which I think will be best to create dummy variables for (Conservative, Labour) and then Lib Dem would be the intercept if I'm not mistaken.

The dependent variable is a Likert Scale and I would like to model the effect of party identification on the ordinal variable to look for significant data etc.

If I was to do this in R, can I use `polr`, do I have to run a separate model for each dummy variable or can I include them all in same model with the variable I haven't created a dummy variable for being the intercept and how will I interpret the results.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! How would you do it for a continuous $y$ variable (e.g., a standard OLS linear regression)?

Comment: @Dave So I am assuming I can create the model with n-1 dummy variables for my categorical independent variables.

Comment: It sounds like, if you had a continuous $y$, you would use a regular ANOVA. Is that accurate?

Comment: @Dave Yes, but due to the ordered nature of the dependent variable I believe ```polr```  is correct

Comment: General resources on ordinal models may be found [here](https://fharrell.com/post/rpo).  There are two functions in the R `rms` package for ordinal regression that give you more graphics and interpretation tools.

Comment: In R, you don't need to create the dummy variables.  You just use the factor variable on the right hand side of the formula, and R will handle it.  However, you choose which contrast coding scheme R uses to do this, if that's of interest.

Comment: In R, I also recommend the *ordinal* package, with is supported by e.g. the *emmeans* package.

Answer (score 1):

You will fit one (ordinal) model with the dummy-coded predictor variable. If you have some other predictor variable, the situation is analogous to [Separate Models vs Flags in the same model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/373890/separate-models-vs-flags-in-the-same-model/373909#373909)

If there is no other predictor variables, the situation is analogout to one-way anova.  Fitting separate regression models for each factor level do not make much sense in that case, since there will be no variation in x ...