# Testing the difference of effect of education on income between men and women --- what is the methodology?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, econometrics

Both income and education are quantitative variables, while gender is of course categorical.

Can I find the linear regression for men and women separately, and then compare the coefficients for education?

After doing that, I want to use an interaction term.

Is this a sound method to test my question?

Comment: This can and should all be done in one model from the start, you will then be able to compare all of these.

Comment: How could you possibly use an interaction if you start with two separate models?  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/373890/separate-models-vs-flags-in-the-same-model/373909#373909