# How to do an interaction in lmRob() function?

Tags: r, regression, interaction, robust

I am trying to compare 2 `lmRob()` models. One for male and one for female gender. Imagine my model like this:

```r
model <- robust::lmRob(Y ~ X_dummy1 + X_dummy2 + X_dummy3 + 
            X_dummy4 + covariate1 + covariate2 + covariate3, 
            data = df)
```

When using gender (0 = female, 1 = male) as interaction, like this:

```r
model <- robust::lmRob(Y ~ X_dummy1* gender + X_dummy2* gender + 
    X_dummy3* gender + X_dummy4* gender + covariate1* gender + 
    covariate2* gender + covariate3* gender, data = df)
```

this error appears:

```r
    Error in lmRob.fit.compute(x, y, x1.idx = x1.idx, nrep = nrep, 
    robust.control = robust.control,  : 
      Singular matrix encountered in FORTRAN subroutine rlfastse
```

Is this not how to include the interaction in the lmRob() function? Do I have other options to compare the models for gender then?

Comment: Looks to be a continuation of https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/637247/how-can-i-compare-the-results-of-two-lmrob-models

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) 
here, but you may have a real statistical question buried 
here. You may want to edit your question to clarify the 
underlying statistical issue. You may find that when you 
understand the statistical concepts involved, the 
software-specific elements are self-evident or at least 
easy to get from the documentation.

Comment: Also see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/117052/replicating-statas-robust-option-in-r,

Answer (score 3):

Your problems seems to be a mixture of statistical and R programming. First, `lmRob` is written to be used (as much as possible ...) as a drop-in replacement for the `lm` function. So how to specify models with the R formula language is exactly as for  `lm`. First, you seems to be making dummys for a factor variable *by hand*. In it place, do something like  `X <- as.factor(X)` and R will make dummys for you (this might solve your singular matrix problem, maybe you made as many dummys as there are levels in `X`?). Then something like

```r
model0 <- robust::lmRob(Y ~ X + covariate1 + covariate2 + covariate3, 
            data = df)

model <- robust::lmRob(Y ~ X * gender +   covariate1 * gender + 
    covariate2 * gender + covariate3 * gender, data = df)
```

Then for model comparison do

```r
anova(model0, model, test="RF")
```

which will compare the models using a robustified F test. If this still gives errors like the one reported, there must be data problems. Could you share the data set?